# Mysql query, use field as column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following table structure

```
+-------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| id    |assigned_to | status    |  group_id     |              
+-------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 1     | 1001       | 1         |    19         |
+-------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 2     | 1001       | 2         |    19         |
+-------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 3     | 1001       | 1         |    18         |
+-------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 4     | 1002       | 2         |    19         |
+-------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 5     | 1002       | 2         |    19         |
+-------+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

I would like to get the information in the following format

```
+-------+------------+-----------+
|       |   1001     |   1002    |          
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 1     |    1       |    0      |   
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 2     |    1       |    2      |   
+-------+------------+-----------+
```

So basically I am looking to use the assigned to field as the column names. Then the rows represent the status. So for example in the table we have two rows where user 1002 has a status of 2, therefore the sum is shown on that particular status row.

Please note that the `group_id` must be 19. Hence why I left out the row with id 3 on my table.

Can someone point me in the right direction. Im sure there is a name for this type of query, but I can't for the life of me put this into words. I have tried various other queries, but none of them even come close to this.

Comment: This is a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. There's workarounds, but the queries become extremely ugly, very very quickly. Do the row->column transformation in your code, and use a conventional query.

Comment: @MarcB thank you for taking the time to answer. Could you possibly expand on this or point me to a piece of documentation for this row->column transformation. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MarcB funnily enough I just spoke to someone on skype who has done this and the query is about 100 lines long and looks terrible. Think i'll go down a php route. I'd rather have a few extra lines of php than an unmanageable unreadable single query.

Comment: basically the workaround only allows for a fixed number of row->column conversions, where you know what the values are. there's no way to make a generic conversion to handle all arbitrary cases, because you'd basically have pivot support anyways. but you basically end up with `select if(field=1, field, 0) as field_1, if (field=2, field, 0) as field_2` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marc B is right, there is no way to pivot a table -i.e. converting the content of a field into columns- unless you make some assumptions, like supossing that the values of assigned_to are somewhat fixed.

On the other hand, this is the kind of problems that can be solved by a program. It is not an easy program, but it can do the job.

I recently made a program similar to this in java, if you are interested I can post the core of it here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think i'll have to do it with a few queries and some code. Appreciate the offer.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to read this article http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=523

i'd be something like

```
SELECT 
  assigned_to, 
  COUNT( CASE assigned_to WHEN '1001' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS '1001', 
  COUNT( CASE assigned_to WHEN '1002' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS '1002'
FROM table
WHERE group_by = 19
GROUP BY assigned_to WITH ROLLUP;
```

or something like that (i haven't tested this code.. )

in the article, he does it using `SUM()` you'd have to do it with `COUNT()` and add a WHERE constraint for the group_id

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, this is what I have in mid, but this assumes you have a fixed number of values in the assigned_to column, and this can't be changed whithout changing the query also.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but @RaulLuna is right, I have a dynamic list of users so unfortunately this will not suffice, upvote for you though.

Comment: @JonPaulH yeap.. in the article they show how to generate this query using a procedure.. or you could generate this query in PHP.. anyway it's still an ugly query :) good luck